Qnap Nas share timeouts
I switch over to Ubuntu 23.10 January of 2024. I have a QNAP 2 bay NAS that I use for all the devices in my network. When I first set up Ubuntu it was able to see the NAS and connect to it without issues.
Today, after a reboot I can no longer connect to the NAS. Ubuntu shows the name of the NAS but when I tried to connect to it, it takes a long time and then gives me a timeout error.
I have two two other windows computers and a Linux laptop (Pop OS) and they are all able to access NAS. I can access the NAS via the web interface and there have been no recently changes to either Ubuntu or NAS from me manually. I am looking for a way to troubleshoot the issue and any information would be helpful.
Ubuntu Version: 23.10



So after much testing it seem like nautilus has bug. It magically worked today.
Regardless, I found an alternative way to connect drives that relies less on Nautilus. Use Fstab file to automatically mount drives to a folder.

Create a folder for the mounts

navigate to /etc/fstab and open the file

Add the entry at the end of file with the following format.The last part starting at rw is optional but needed if write and delete permissions are needed for the shares.
//ServerIP/Share /mtn/nas cifs username=XX,password=XX,uid=XX,gid=XX,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0


Reboot computer


Note: if you file path contains spaces use \40 to escape the space.  Below is an example.
//ServerIP/another\40Share /mtn/nas cifs 

Note:the id command on the CLI. Will show the ID and GID of the user.
